# Spring Asynchronous Processing Does not Return To View

Tags: spring, servlets, spring-mvc, asynchronous

I'm using the Spring MVC asyncronous processing but the controller does not return a view on web browser.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/generateGM", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Callable<ModelAndView> generateGMReport(@RequestParam("countryCode") int countryCode, ModelAndView mv) {

        Callable<ModelAndView> c = new GenericCallable(countryCode, reportDao, mv);

        return c;
    }

@Override
    public ModelAndView call() throws Exception {

        List<CostReport> gmList = reportDao.generateGrossMarginReport(countryCode);

        mv.setViewName("gmReport");
        mv.addObject("gmList", gmList);

        return mv;
    }
```

I had tried to modify the code to return Callable but it still does not return to the specified view name.

I'm using JBoss 7.1 as.

There is warning during deployment :

```
WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-7) 

JBAS011006: Not installing optional component 

org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest 
due to exception: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: 
JBAS011054: 
Could not find default constructor for class 
org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest
```

Reason: Perhaps sitemesh cannot set the response object from Spring MVC framework (AsynContext).

What is the reason ?

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Kindly provide any guidance. Please let me know if need further information.

Comment: I tried to disable the sitemesh filer and it has return some result but there is no return html with sitemesh fileter enable. Moreover, there is WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-7) 

JBAS011006: Not installing optional component 

org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest 
due to exception: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: 
JBAS011054: 
Could not find default constructor for class 
org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Sitemesh filter does some post-processing at the end of a request, it needs to support the Servlet 3 async request feature in order for this to work. When the initial Servlet container thread exits and the response remains open. If the Sitemesh filter is unaware of this, it will attempt to complete processing to early.

Comment: Any concrete solution ? I may try the latest sitemesh 3 jar.

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expect on sitemesh. But it's a servlet also so they follow the "chain of command" pattern which means it's possible it fail to transfer the correct url you need. can you post you config for async spring and sitemesh config in web.xml

Answer (score -1):

It may be helpful. Return as a **String** instead of **ModelAndView**.